# pynput: Holding a hotkey doesn't trigger it multiple times

Tags: python, pynput

I created some hotkeys with python's pynput module. According to their [documentation for creating global hotkeys](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#global-hotkeys), using the following code block is how we can create multiple hotkteys easily with less code.

```py
from pynput import keyboard

def on_activate_h():
    print('<ctrl>+<alt>+h pressed')

def on_activate_i():
    print('<ctrl>+<alt>+i pressed')

with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
        '<ctrl>+<alt>+h': on_activate_h,
        '<ctrl>+<alt>+i': on_activate_i}) as h:
    h.join()
```

The way this works is that when I hold `ctrl+alt` and press `h`, it triggers the `on_activate_h` function, in the same way holding `ctrl+alt` and pressing `i` triggers `on_activate_i` function.
But when I hold `ctrl+alt+h`, it **doesn't trigger** the `on_activate_h` function multiple times in a row.
If I want to trigger `on_activate_h` multiple times, I am having to release `h` and again press `h`. Is there a way to make this program trigger `on_activate_h` multiple times when I hold `ctrl+alt+h` without releasing and pressing `h` multiple times ?